# How can I make quick environment or command changes in LaTeX

Tags: filetype-tex

I have a large body of LaTeX text (a whole book) which has `\textit{}` and `\textbf{}` commands interchanged in some places. In other places they are completely missing. How do I create quick shortcuts in Vim so that I can do the following:

- Switch between `\textit{}` to `\textbf{}` and vice versa without affecting what is inside `{}`.
- Wrap word or phrase under cursor into either of the `\textit{}` or `\textbf{}` commands.
- Remove either the `\textit{}` or `\textbf{}` commands where they are not needed but put in by mistake.

Comment: These are not environments, by the way, but commands. [There's a difference](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8373/77871).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use [the vimtex plugin](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex), you can:

1. Change an enclosing command using `csc`:

   [image]
2. According to the help, a `ysc` corresponding to the commands offered by `surround.vim` isn't available, but can be added. See [`:h vimtex-faq-surround`](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/blob/master/doc/vimtex.txt#L1725):

   ```
                                                             *vimtex-faq-surround*
   Q: |vimtex| provides `dse`, `dsc`, `cse`, and `csc`.  These seem to be inspired by
      |surround.vim|.  Does |vimtex| also provide the corresponding `yse` and `ysc`?
   A: The mentioned mappings are indeed inspired by |surround.vim|.  However,
      |vimtex| does not provide `yse` and `ysc`.  If you use |surround.vim|, then
      the asked for mappings may be easily added if one adds the following lines
      to ones `vimrc` file: >

     augroup latexSurround
        autocmd!
        autocmd FileType tex call s:latexSurround()
     augroup END

     function! s:latexSurround()
        let b:surround_{char2nr("e")}
          \ = "\\begin{\1environment: \1}\n\t\r\n\\end{\1\1}"
        let b:surround_{char2nr("c")} = "\\\1command: \1{\r}"
     endfunction
   <
   ```
3. Delete an enclosing command using `dsc`.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out and let you know how it worked out.

Comment: I just want to mention that the current support for commands is only very simple. This is because it is really quite hard to parse LaTeX/TeX commands, i.e., how can I know the number of arguments to a specific command? (Answer: I can't, if I don't know the command definition.) Thus `csc` only works if the cursor is on the actual command or the first argument.